# Drop level from one specific column

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns

Inspired by [Pandas: drop a level from a multi-level column index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233488/pandas-drop-a-level-from-a-multi-level-column-index)

I have a multilevel dataframe:

```
  | l |   a   |
  +---+---+---+
  |   | b | c |
--+---+---+---+
0 | a ¦ 1 | 2 |
1 | b ¦ 3 | 4 |
```

I need to flatten the column `a` at level 0

So that it would look like:

```
  +---+---+---+
  | l | b | c |
--+---+---+---+
0 | a ¦ 1 | 2 |
1 | b ¦ 3 | 4 |
```

`df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()` produces

```
  +---+---+---+
  |   | b | c |
--+---+---+---+
0 | a ¦ 1 | 2 |
1 | b ¦ 3 | 4 |
```

I am struggling to produce a toy example as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df.columns = [c[-1] for c in df.columns]
```