# Pandas: Is there a way to use something like 'droplevel' and in process, rename the other level using the dropped level labels as prefix/suffix?

Tags: python, pandas, rename, multiple-columns, multi-index

Screenshot of the query below:

[image: Groupby Query]

Is there a way to easily drop the upper level column index and a have a single level with labels such as `points_prev_amax`, `points_prev_amin`, `gf_prev_amax`, `gf_prev_amin` and so on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` for set new column names:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)

Or:

df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,2,1],
                   'B':[4,5,6,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,1],
                   'D':[1,3,5,9]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  7  1
1  2  5  8  3
2  2  6  9  5
3  1  4  1  9

df = df.groupby('A').agg([max, min])

df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
   B_max  B_min  C_max  C_min  D_max  D_min
A                                          
1      4      4      7      1      9      1
2      6      5      9      8      5      3
```

---

```
print (['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns])
['B_max', 'B_min', 'C_max', 'C_min', 'D_max', 'D_min']

df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns]
print (df)
   B_max  B_min  C_max  C_min  D_max  D_min
A                                          
1      4      4      7      1      9      1
2      6      5      9      8      5      3
```

If need `prefix` simple swap items of tuples:

```
df.columns = ['_'.join((col[1], col[0])) for col in df.columns]
print (df)
   max_B  min_B  max_C  min_C  max_D  min_D
A                                          
1      4      4      7      1      9      1
2      6      5      9      8      5      3
```

Another solution:

```
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(i[1], i[0]) for i in df.columns]
print (df)
   max_B  min_B  max_C  min_C  max_D  min_D
A                                          
1      4      4      7      1      9      1
2      6      5      9      8      5      3
```

If `len` of columns is big (10^6), then rather use [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().str.join('_')
```

Answer (score 2):

Using @jezrael's setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,2,1],
                   'B':[4,5,6,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,1],
                   'D':[1,3,5,9]})

df = df.groupby('A').agg([max, min])
```

---

Assign new columns with

```
from itertools import starmap

def flat(midx, sep=''):
    fstr = sep.join(['{}'] * midx.nlevels)
    return pd.Index(starmap(fstr.format, midx))

df.columns = flat(df.columns, '_')

df
```

[image]

Comment: @jezrael This is a new one I came up with today ;-)  comprehension is still slightly faster.

Comment: I think there is one exception - if len of columns is very big (few 10^6), then this is faster. `df.columns = df.columns.to_series().str.join('_')`. But I think practically len of `columns` is small, so list comprehension is better.

Comment: @jezrael it is also faster when there are more levels.  `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('ABCD'), range(4), list('wxyz')])`

Comment: Btw, I am surprised then no function for this.

Comment: @jezrael me too.  One of us should start contributing to pandas :-)

Comment: No me, because I am not low code developer as you. so you win it ;)

Comment: I am going check github if some more info about this function.