# Split Multilevel dataframe into different csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Suppose I have the following dataframe :

```
    X       Y
   ---+---+---+---
    A | B | A | B
--+---+---+---+---
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8
2 | 9 | 10| 11| 12
```

I want to split it based on the multilevel index recursively and save them in a csv file.

For example a file name X_A.csv should contain the following dataframe:

```
    X 
   ---
    A 
--+---
0 | 1 
1 | 5 
2 | 9
```

Similarly the file X_B.csv should store a dataframe as :

```
    X 
   ---
    B 
--+---
0 | 2 
1 | 6 
2 | 10
```

and so on for Y_A and Y_B.

I am looking for a Pythonic ( or efficient) way to do this rather than iterating over the column values separately as the code is quite large. I tried using the techniques [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233488/pandas-drop-a-level-from-a-multi-level-column-index?rq=1) by dropping the column levels and storing the individual columns but I want to it in such a way that I don't have to explicitly mention the column names since the dataframe may expand ( i.e. at the top most level there might be 4 columns say W, X, Y and Z).

Comment: Why not combine two level column names to one

Comment: If panda.Dataframe subclass numpy.Ndarray, can't you use [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing) on it to select the columns you're interested in, and then use the object's method to exoprt to CSV

Comment: @Wen I do not want to change the original df that is why I don't want to combine the two level column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list_of_df = [df[i].to_frame() for i in df.columns]
```

With @JohnGalt's suggestion to csv:

```
_ = [df[i].to_frame().to_csv('{0}_{1}'.format(*i)) for i in df.columns]
```

Output:

list_of_df[0]

```
   X
   A
0  1
1  5
2  9
```

list_of_df[1]

```
    X
    B
0   2
1   6
2  10
```

...

list_of_df[3]

```
    Y
    B
0   4
1   8
2  12
```

Comment: Neat and `...to_csv('{0}_{1}.csv'.format(*i))` for csv.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

Rename *`df.columns`*

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(x) for x in df.columns]

df

   X_A  X_B  Y_A  Y_B
0                    
0    1    2    3    4
1    5    6    7    8
2    9   10   11   12

for c in df:
     df[c].reset_index().to_csv(c + '.csv')
```

---

**Option 2**

*`groupby`* levels

```
for name, g in df.groupby(level=[0, 1], axis=1):
    g.to_csv('{0}_{1}.csv'.format(*name))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `apply` for that.

#### Create example df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['X', 'Y'], ['A', 'B']],labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=index, data=np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4)))

>>> df
Out[]:
   X      Y
   A  B   A   B
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11
```

#### Save as separate CSV files:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.to_csv('_'.join(x.name) + '.csv'), axis=0)
```

This will produce the desired output. For example `X_A.csv` contains:

```
0,0
1,4
2,8
```

If you want to include the axis name into the csv, add `header=True` as argument to `to_csv`, then `X_A.csv` will contain:

```
,X
,A
0,0
1,4
2,8
```