# Pandas Data frame Pivot Reset

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply pivot table on a data frame by using

```
intractionTableClicks = pd.pivot_table(read_sql_preroll_interaction,index = ["PLACEMENT"],values=["VWR_CLICKTHROUGH"],
                                               columns=["CLICK_TAG"],aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0)
```

but the output is coming like[image]
I want this to be like this [image]
I've already tried `intractionTableClicks.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: Abhilash just remove those square brackets for the column names in your code.

Comment: @Dark it's not giving the output as expected.

Comment: The answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233488/pandas-drop-a-level-from-a-multi-level-column-index