# Pandas DataFrame plot: specify column from MultiIndex for secondary_y

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, multi-index

I am plotting a multi-index columns DataFrame.

What is the syntax to specify the column(s) to be plotted on secondary_y using the `.plot` method of pandas DataFrame?

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mt_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['first', 'second']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(20, len(mt_idx))), columns=mt_idx)
```

**My Attempts**

```
df.plot(secondary_y=('B', 'second'))
df.plot(secondary_y='(B, second)')
```

None of the above worked, as all the lines were plotted on the principal y-axis.

Comment: According to the documentation you should be able to user your form of passing a tuple or a list. But I tried it also and it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to plot each column, then specify `secondary=True`. Doing it the following way requires you to specifiy the axes to which they will be plotted:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

mt_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['first', 'second']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(20, len(mt_idx))), columns=mt_idx)

df.A.plot(ax=ax)
df.B.plot(ax=ax, secondary_y=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might [drop the upper column index level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44812758/4124317). If you don't want to modify the original dataframe, this could be done on a copy of it.

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('_'.join)

df2.plot(secondary_y=('B_second'))
```

[image]

Comment: `df2.columns = df2.columns.map('_'.join)` is cleaner :)