# How to merge all data-frames in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary `dict` contains many (more than 100) dataframes. Each dataframe contains two variable `name` and 'value_i'.  For example, the first dataframe in this dictionary `dict[1]` looks like the following:

```
name  value_1
A      1
B      1.1 
C      2
```

Similarly, the second dataframe in this dictionary `dict2` looks like the following:

```
name  value_2
A      1
B      1.1 
D      1.3
```

I want to merge all dataframes within this dictionary by common variable `name`.

The expected outcome should looks like the following:

```
name  value_1   value_2
A      1         1
B      1.1       1.1
C      2         nan
D     nan           1.3
```

I know I can do `pd.merge[dict[i], dict[i-1], how = 'outer', on = 'name'` many times to merge all dataframes together. But this is too inefficient.

I tried `pd.concat(dict.values(), axis = 1, join='outer'` But `concat` dont allow me to merge by key variable.

Can anyone teach me how to do it more efficiently please?

Comment: What is the expected output for your example?

Comment: You should take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) as it covers a tremendous amount of merging info.

Comment: I am not sure about all the answers. Looks like you want `pd.join(dict.keys(),how = 'outer', on = 'name')`, which is covered by the duplicate target.

Comment: For pd.join(dict.keys(),how = 'outer', on = 'name', I got the following error message   module 'pandas' has no attribute 'join'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df1                                                                                                                
  name  value_1
0    A      1.0
1    B      1.1
2    C      2.0
>>> df2                                                                                                                
  name  value_2
0    A      1.0
1    B      1.1
2    D      1.3
```

and

```
>>> d = {1: df1, 2: df2}
```

you can issue

```
>>> from functools import partial, reduce                                                                              
>>>                                                                                                                    
>>> my_reduce = partial(pd.merge, on='name', how='outer')                                                              
>>> reduce(my_reduce, d.values())                                                                                      
  name  value_1  value_2
0    A      1.0      1.0
1    B      1.1      1.1
2    C      2.0      NaN
3    D      NaN      1.3
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider you have multiple items in `dict`

```
d={i : j.set_index('name') for i,j in d.items()}
yourdf=pd.concat(d,axis=1)
```

Comment: Works if the name column in OP's dfs have all unique values. If that's the case I'm wondering why they ask about a merging, though.

Comment: In this case, the variable name changed to (i, 'value_i'). Is there anyway to keep the original variable name.

Comment: @timgeb since the merge is well explained in the link 101 , so that I am trying some thing different

Comment: @fly36 check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233488/pandas-drop-a-level-from-a-multi-level-column-index