# how to drop all columns under a nested column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe much like the one in this question:
[Pandas: drop a level from a multi-level column index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233488/pandas-drop-a-level-from-a-multi-level-column-index)

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("a", "b"), ("a", "c")])
pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=cols)

    a
   ---+--
    b | c
--+---+--
0 | 1 | 2
1 | 3 | 4
```

In the question reference above, the questioner wanted to know how to drop the column heading `a`. I would like to know how to drop it and all the columns underneath it (in this case `b`) so that the resulting dataframe looks like:

```
  | c
--+--
0 | 2
1 | 4
```

can you help me achieve this?

Comment: By "all the columns underneath it" you mean the first column under that header?

Comment: As pointed out, `'a'` is the first level label for both columns in your dataframe. So both `'b'` and `'c'` are "under" `'a'`. Could you clarify what your intention is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for clarity, I think both 'b' and 'c' are contained under 'a'. However, you can select which you wish to drop in the following code.

First build the DataFrame:

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("a", "b"), ("a", "c")])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=cols)
```

Then drop the column ('a','b')... and also drop the 'a' level, leaving you with 'c'.

```
df.drop([('a', 'b')], axis=1,inplace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

The resulting DataFrame looks like this.

```
    c
0   2
1   4
```

Comment: thank you, you're right, my attention to detail was lacking but you knew what I meant. this answer works great

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following assuming what you call "the column underneath", is the first one.

```
z['a'].drop(z['a'].columns[0], axis=1)
```

This is a quick answer based on the result expected, sorry if it seems dumb, but maybe you can be more precise in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need this but you can using groupby achieve this

```
df=df.groupby(level=0,axis=0).apply(lambda  x : x.iloc[:,1:])
df.columns=df.columns.get_level_values(1)
df
   c
0  2
1  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select just that slice from the columns then rename the column header to a single level header:

```
df.loc(axis=1)[:,'c'].set_axis(['c'], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

Output:

```
   c
0  2
1  4
```