# Summing all values ​from one day in a time series in pandas pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

how to calculate the sum of all values ​​from one day in a time series in pd pivot? 
My pandas pivot looks like this:

```
       Date    2019-10-01         2019-10-02          2019-10-03       ....          2019-12-01 
Hospital_name                                                         

Hospital1          12                 15                  16           ....              12                                                              
Hospital2          10                 17                  14           ....              12 
Hospital3          15                 20                  12           ....              12
```

and I want to pivot such like this:

```
       Date    2019-10-01         2019-10-02           2019-10-03      ....          2019-12-01 

Sum                37                 52                   42          ....               36
```

My data type is:

```
type(df.columns[0])
out: str
```

```
type(df.columns[1])
out: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the first dataframe your original dataframe or is it a pivot?

Comment: It is a pivot..

Comment: Did you try `.sum()` on your pivot table? Can you post a sample of your actual data frame before pivot?

Answer (score 1):

`sum` is your friend here, as stated in the comments. Using dummy df:

```
              2019-10-01 2019-10-02 2019-10-03
Hospital_name       John       Maya      Robin
h1                    12         12         42
h2                    15         55         13
h3                    14         42         22
```

You simply ignore the first row and use `sum`:

```
df.loc[df.index!='Hospital_name'].sum()

2019-10-01     41.0
2019-10-02    109.0
2019-10-03     77.0
dtype: float64
```

EDIT: It looks like you have multiindex columns. You can drop this using:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

(taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22233719/9758660))

Answer (score 1):

```py
new_df = df.transpose()
new_df["Total"] = df[0:].sum()
df = new_df.transpose()
```

`new_df` is assigned as df but a transposed version 
`new_df["Total"] = df[0:].sum()` adds the Total columns 
`df = new_df.transpose()` brings back the table as it was in the first place

For a better experience you can always try each line in a jupyter notebook or lab to see what happens.
And please if you are satisfied with the answer, mark it as accepted

Thank you