# Is there a way to remove one of the indexes when printing a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, in the dataframe below, I want to remove the top index (sum/lambda) so it prints in a cleaner fashion. I'm going to be then exporting that dataframe to excel.

[image]

Comment: `df.droplevel(axis=1)` ?

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()`

Comment: @anky  Possible duplicate? [Pandas: drop a level from a multi-level column index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22233488/13328010)

Comment: @DavideBrex thank you for the link

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I thought droplevel might change the format. That's work though, thank you.