# Removing columns selectively from multilevel index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Say we have a dataframe like this and want to remove columns when certain conditions met.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
np.arange(2, 14).reshape(-1, 4),
index=list('ABC'),
columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    ['data1', 'data2','data1','data2'],
    ['F', 'K','R','X'],
    ['C', 'D','E','E']
], names=['meter', 'Sleeper','sweeper'])
)

df
```

[image]

then lets say we want to remove cols only when `meter == data1` and `sweeper == E`
so I tried

```
df = df.drop(('data1','E'),axis = 1)
```

> KeyError: 'E'

second try

```
df.drop(('data1','E'), axis = 1, level = 2)
```

> KeyError: "labels [('data1', 'E')] not found in level"

[Pandas: drop a level from a multi-level column index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233488/pandas-drop-a-level-from-a-multi-level-column-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) doesn't support selection over split levels (`[0,2]` here). We can create a mask with the conditions instead using [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
# keep where not ((level0 is 'data1') and (level2 is 'E'))
col_mask = ~((df.columns.get_level_values(0) == 'data1')
             & (df.columns.get_level_values(2) == 'E'))
df = df.loc[:, col_mask]
```

We can also do this by integer location by excluding the locs that are in a particular index slice, however, this is overall less clear and less flexible:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice['data1', :, 'E']
cols = [i for i in range(len(df.columns))
        if i not in df.columns.get_locs(idx)]
df = df.iloc[:, cols]
```

Either approach produces `df`:

```
meter   data1 data2    
Sleeper     F     K   X
sweeper     C     D   E
A           2     3   5
B           6     7   9
C          10    11  13
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do them individually, since they are on different levels:

```py
df.drop('data1', axis=1, level='meter').drop('E', axis = 1, level='sweeper')
Out[833]: 
meter   data2
Sleeper     K
sweeper     D
A           3
B           7
C          11
```