# How to convert column index to column name in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
arrays = [['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
          ['Captive', 'Wild', 'Captive', 'Wild']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('Animal', 'Type'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Max Speed': [390., 350., 30., 20.]},
                  index=index)
df = df.unstack(1)
```

As a result, I've got a dataframe:

```
       Max Speed       
Type     Captive   Wild
Animal
Falcon     390.0  350.0
Parrot      30.0   20.0
```

How can I convert column index to the normal column for further calculations?

E.g. when I tried to calculate the ratio:

```
ratio = df.Captive / df.Wild
```

I am getting an error:

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Captive'

Comment: What do you mean "convert column index to the normal column"? You can use the MultiIndex `df[('Max Speed', 'Captive')] / df[('Max Speed', 'Wild')]`  or droplevel `df = df.unstack(1).droplevel(level=0, axis=1)` if you want to get rid of `Max Speed`.

Comment: @HenryEcker as far as I uderstand - the second suggestion should be `df = df.droplevel(level=0, axis=1)`

Comment: I was adding it to the end of your already present code (`df = df.unstack(1)`). @Andrey The multi level comes from unstacking so the removal should be in the same chain.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate since the accepted answer matches [BENY's answer from 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53449204/15497888) "`df.columns=df.columns.get_level_values(1)`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)`

after that you can use ratio = `df.Captive / df.Wild`

Answer (score 1):

`df` is now a dataframe that *contains another* dataframe.

This'll work:

```py
ratio = df['Max Speed'].Captive / df['Max Speed'].Wild
```